# How to append list of all results from a For loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, printing, append

I'm struggling to get a function of mine to work. Here's the basis of what it is:

```
#for example:
data=[(b),(c),(d),(e)]

results=[]
for x in data: #this goes through each row of the data
    # body_code executes. This part is mostly just changing types, etc
    a=final_body_code
    results.append(a)
print results

#output should be: results=[(b),(c),(d),(e)] #After changing types of b,c,d,e etc.

#The body of the code does not matter at this point, it's just the appending which i'm
#struggling with.
```

However, when I do this it does not seem to append a to the results list. I'm a newbie when it comes to python, so please help!

Comment: provide us with input/expected output ?

Comment: First, what is `->`? Is this supposed to be a comment? Second, are you sure `data` is not empty or None? Third, what do you mean it goes through each row? And many more questions.. provide more details.

Comment: `print` out `data` and ensure that these are non-empty (a.k.a. `None`).  Is `data` a nested list?

Comment: Give us a [minimal runnable example that demonstrates the problem when you run it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question does not include enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Make sure the inner for loop is being reached. put a print statement inside the loop. If `data` is empty the results will be empty since the loop will be skipped

Comment: Please post the output you are getting. That is the proper method of appending to an array you're using.

Comment: I recommend to learn and use list comprehensions in Python.

Answer (score 3):

You should add examples.

Maybe you have some problem in `a=final_body_code` which a result is `None`

However, a little improvement to @Mrinal Wahal answer, using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
results = [final_body_code(i) for i in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think This Is What You're Willing To Do.

```
data=[(b),(c),(d),(e)]

results=[]

for x in data:
    results.append(x)

print results
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data = [b, c, d, e]

results = []

results.extend(final_body_code(i) for i in data)

return results
```